# Using same algorithm in web and Android application

Tags: architecture, web-applications, android

For my project I need to use same algorithm for both web and Android application.

I thought about handling the algorithm server side but I feel this would put too much unnecessary load on the server so I would prefer it to be handled client side.

What approach would be recommended for this situation to avoid both load on the server and rewriting the code?

Answer (score -1):

Do it with JS and use WebView on Android. This is common practice, e.g. "sign up" form is commonly done this way.